# Why does Jenkins Active Directory lookup fail occasionally?

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

We have Jenkins running on a CentoOS Linux server, connected to an Active Directory Server for authentication.

Authentication works flawlessly most of the time, however, at as far as I can tell, random intervals, Jenkins will fail to authenticate some users. This can be temporarily fixed by resetting their passwords, however after a few weeks, it will stop working again.

```
Nov 20, 2019 2:04:23 PM WARNUNG hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl bind
Failed to authenticate while binding to 192.168.169.10:3268
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 532, v3839]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3154)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2886)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2800)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2699)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2673)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(LdapCtx.java:2669)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:721)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:599)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:410)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:303)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:225)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
    at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:74)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Nov 20, 2019 2:04:23 PM WARNUNG hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
Credential exception trying to authenticate against ourdomaincontroller.local domain
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Either no such user 'CN=Firstame Lastname,OU=Benutzer,OU=ourunit,DC=ourdomaincontroller,DC=local' or incorrect password
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:614)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:410)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider$1.call(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:340)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:303)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:225)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
    at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:74)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(Note: username, organizational unit and domain controller have been replaced for privacy reasons)

The relevant section of our config is this:

```
  <securityRealm class="hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm" plugin="active-directory@2.16">
    <domains>
      <hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
        <name>ourdomaincontroller.local</name>
        <servers>192.168.169.10:3268</servers>
        <bindName>domainadmin@domain.de</bindName>
        <bindPassword>{somepassword}</bindPassword>
        <tlsConfiguration>TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES</tlsConfiguration>
      </hudson.plugins.active__directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain>
    </domains>
    <startTls>true</startTls>
    <groupLookupStrategy>AUTO</groupLookupStrategy>
    <removeIrrelevantGroups>false</removeIrrelevantGroups>
    <cache>
      <size>256</size>
      <ttl>600</ttl>
    </cache>
  </securityRealm>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key part:

```
LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 532, v3839
```

particularly `data 532`.

That is the hex value of the Win32 error code of what is actually wrong. If you convert `532` to decimal, it's `1330`, which is easier to find on Microsoft's list of [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-#error_password_expired):

> ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED
>
> 1330 (0x532)
>
> The password for this account has expired.

The behaviour you describe is entirely normal if you have a policy that enforces that passwords be changed periodically.

There is also an easier-to-read list [here](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) of all the error codes that could happen while logging in.